# Openstack not able to connect port 5000

Tags: centos7, openstack

I recently started working on openstack-train(centos7). I created 2 nodes on virtualbox which are on subnet 192.168.56.0/24. I read and followed the official train docs and encountered issue when i was installing keystone module. When i run any openstack command like openstack network list i get this error.

> Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://node1:5000/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL. Unable to establish connection to http://node1:5000/v3/auth/tokens : HTTPConnectionPool(host='node1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7492466650>: Failed to establish new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',))

PS: node1 is the controller node has 192.168.56.2 static ip and installed keystone on it.

The procedures i have taken:

- Did the environment config.
- I reinstalled keystone and checked every step on the docs.
- Added node1 192.168.56.1 on /etc/hosts and can be pinged and connect with apache server on 80.
- Disabled firewall and tried to connect to the node1:5000/v3 but no luck.

I was on this step:
https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/train/install/keystone-users-rdo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my preconfigured apache server somehow conflicted keystone web api. So solution was I deleted the node1 vm entirely and did it all again. It worked :/

Edit 1: So solution for this problem was installing the selinux module.

```
sudo yum install -y openstack-selinux
```